# wpf mvvm how to cancel click event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I have two windows: parent and child. I'm opening and closing child window by clicking button "Open window". Child window closes on lose_focus event. But when child window is opened, I click on "Open window" child window loses focus, closes, then button_click event raises and child window reopens. I whant to cancel button_click event if focus_lost event was raised before it. How can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you just disable the "Open Window" button when opening a child and only enable it when your lost focus event gets triggered? Your current idea might make for one confusing UI. With the disable button approach, your user can't even click the button when a child window is open, the click will go to the parent Window instead of the button and you'd have your requirement.

Comment: so your button is usable only to open the window. The `LostFocus` is always fired first.